# Cambio de datos en una tabla sql

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una BD en SQL con dos tablas
Estás contienen ID, MONTO(Float)
Desearía saber cómo cambiar los datos en la columna monto ya que guarde datos en esta pero están en millones y deseo pasarlos a miles todos los campos es decir son montos en formato de dinero y en la columna están de esta forma
1300000.80
45558886
3600500
Lo que deseo es modificar la información completa de esa columna pasar por una división a todos los datos (Monto/1000) y está quede asi luego los datos en la tb
13000.8
45558
...

Comment: Puedes hacer en el select la division que necesitas select CAMPO/1000 from tutabla

Comment: Gracias... Desconocía que se podían hacer operaciones matemáticas así, soy nuevo en esto de la programación ^^, eso solventó mi pregunta ahora si quiero es en realidad hacerle un update y no un select, para que me quedé los montos así es posible?

Comment: Gracias..... Lo deduje solo por la respuesta que me diste lo que hice fue update tb SET monto=monto/1000

Comment: Igual ahi te deje la respuesta, si te sirvio marcala como correcta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer el update seria asi

```
UPDATE tutabla SET monto = monto/1000 from tutabla where id=id
```

Con esto deberia ser suficiente para que te funcione y te actualice los campos

antes del update
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues del update
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas cambiar todas las columnas es esto

```
UPDATE 'NAME_TABLE'
SET MONTO = 1000
```

Si quieres cambiar a columnas específicas

```
UPDATE 'NAME_TABLE'
SET MONTO = 1000
WHERE ID='ID'
```

Las comillas las pones siempre y cuando el ID sea un caracter.

Comment: Hola, no es eso lo que deseó lograr, lo que quiero es que en la columna monto que hay valores de esta forma
1000000, 34000000, 50000000, 34000000, estos se transformen en 1000, 3400, ... Es decir pasarlos de millones a miles

Comment: @EthanfDavid puedes ser mas especifico? la verdad no entiendo muy bien que quieres lograr

Comment: En la tb hay una columna llamada montos y esta tiene montos en millones deseo pasarlos por una división para bajarlos de millones a cientos o miles como son muchos campos deseo hacerlo de una manera que no me toque ir de campo en campo cambiando los valores

Comment: Una solución rápida que te podría dar, es cambiar tu tipo de dato a varchar y poner la cantidad de dígitos que desees, por ejemplo varchar(5) y solo te mostrara 10000, ahora si haces eso no se podrá revertir.

Comment: Y si usas php podrias usar la funcion substr_replace() dentro de un while, y mandar a actualizar todo eso, pero es solo si quieres reducir digitos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces es con un substring, cortar la cadena en la posicion que necesitas para que quede en miles

```
select substring(convert(nvarchar,1000000),1,4)
```

este query da este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya paso de ser 1 millon a mil

Y con este mismo substring podrias hacer un update para que los datos te queden guardados en tu tabla con el formato que quieres

Comment: Hola, evita realizar varias respuestas en la misma publicación, realiza solo una basada en [ask], saludos.